# How long to wait before reapplying for the UK visa after refusal

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, dependent-visa

I came to UK in July 2012 on Tier 2 General Migrant Visa. My wife recently applied for her visa under the Tier 2 General Migrant Dependent Category. However, it got refused 2 days ago, because of lack of documents supporting that the relationship is subsisting and ongoing.

She has been given the right to lodge an appeal using IAFT-2 form within the next 28 days. However, we have decided not to go down that route and instead reapply again with all the additional documents submitted. Since, we have all those proofs (wedding photographs, chat history, etc).

My question is, how long does she have to wait before reapplying? Does she have to wait for 28 days before reapplying (i.e., after the time limit to lodge an appeal is over)?

Comment: The ECO isn't going to care as much about chat transcripts as they will about proof that you two have a monetary relationship. Do you have plane tickets for time you've spent together? Do you have proof that you've spent money in your marriage to see / be with each other? They will care about that much more than chat transcripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no required interval between a refusal and a fresh application; she can apply once her passport has been returned from the consulate.  She does not have to sit out the 28 day appeal window.

To avoid a second refusal, the fresh application should remedy all of the refusal reasons and contemplate any additional refusal grounds that may emerge when the documents are examined by an Entry Clearance Officer.

Comment: My wife also sent an inquiry via email to the UK immigration office and she has got the following response:

"With regards to your query, if you choose to re-apply rather than appeal you can do so at any time thank you."